# Web elements not showing in China

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, atg

I am having a very strange issue. I have an international website built with ATG/BCC Ecommerce framework. On the product page, I am using JavaScript to display size options related to a style. My issue is ONLY IN CHINA the sizes do not appear at all. I am not able to reproduce the issue, but customers are calling and complaining. I have had several people in China test this issue, and they are not able to reproduce either. The customers have tried different browsers and clearing their cache, but are still unable to see the sizes. I have read that China blocks certain websites, but since some users in China do not have the issue, I am assuming it is not that.

I really don't think it's an issue with my code, since it works fine in every other region and for most Chinese users.

Does anybody have an idea what might be causing this issue only in China?

HTML

```
<div id="product-sizes">
    <%-- Sizes will be rendered using the JS template below --%>
</div>
<script type="text/template" id="tml-productsizes">
    <ul>{{#sizes}}<li class="{{cssClass}} {{selected}}" data-name="{{key}}">{{name}}</li>{{/sizes}}</ul>
</script>
```

Script

```
var $productSizesTemplate = $("#tml-productsizes");
if (typeof isColor !== "undefined" && isColor) {
    this.renderSizes($productSizesEl, $productSizesTemplate, this.getSelectedColor());
}
renderSizes: function ($targetEl, $template, color) {
        var templatedata = [],
            productSizes = this.sizes, // array of {key: "m", value: "med"}
            isPartialSale = this.isPartialSale(),
            colorSizes = this.getColorSizes(color);


        for (var i = 0, len = productSizes.length; i < len; i++ ) {
            var size = productSizes[i],
                sku = this.skus[color+size.key];

                templatedata.push({
                    'cssClass': ($.inArray(size.key, colorSizes) >= 0)? 'size ' + ((sku && sku.onSale) ? "is-onsale": ''):'size unavailable',
                    'key': size.key,
                    'name': size.value,
                    'selected': (this.getSelectedSize() === size.key )? 'selected': undefined
                });
        }

        $targetEl.html(Mustache.render($template.html(), {sizes:templatedata}));
    });
```

Comment: @ochi was thinking something like that. How would it work for some users in China if that is the case though?

Comment: browser version? (sorry re-read your question, that's prolly not it)

Comment: They are using multiple versions of Chrome: 25, 45, and the latest are the versions we have seen.

Comment: that's a tough one... is your app/template able to handle their locale? (zh_CN, zh_HANS, zh_HANT, etc)

Comment: just a reminder, there is still a scary number of XP users in china running browsers that wraps ie6 core. For those who has problems, have you attempted making their "View source" and show you the html that is rendered in their browser?

Comment: @ochi yes it is able to handle their local (zh_CN).

Comment: @Ji_in_coding wow this is good to know. We are going to ask the next customer to View Source, and also show us the Console in hopes of finding an error.

Comment: @Ji_in_coding we are showing 8% of our users are on an XP machine.

Comment: I was able to test on an XP Machine and did not experience the issue.

Comment: My guess is jquery is blocked by the Chinese firewall.  Suggest you ask a customer to look to see if the request for the jquery lib(s) are timing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the issue. In my code I had a reference to jQuery that sat on Google's servers. The QA team tested using software that allowed them to use a computer in China. They found that the jQuery from Google's CDN was taking up to 50 SECONDS TO LOAD at times!! I moved the jQuery file to our CDN and that solved the problem.

The great firewall of China....